# discord.jsで自分のbotが参加しているサーバーを取得したい

Tags: node.js, discord

discord.jsで自分のbotが参加しているサーバー取得したいんですけどどうすればいいですか

Comment: お使いの discord.js のバージョンを質問文を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

discord.js v11の場合:

```js
client.guilds.map(guild => guild.name).join("\n");
```

discord.js v12の場合:

```js
client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.name).join("\n");
```